# macOS 13 で M5StackCPlus にデータのアップロードができない

Tags: macos, platformio

M5StackCPlusにプログラムをアップロードができません。

MacからM5Stackが認識されていることは、下記の通り確認済みです。

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep M5
        M5stack:
```

[VCPドライバ](https://ftdichip.com/drivers/vcp-drivers/)は、`Mac OS X10.15 and macOS 11/12`に対応した1.5.0をMacOS13にインストールしました。

下記の通りデバイスが作成されていることを確認済みです。

```
$ ls /dev/{tty,cu}.* | tr '[0-9]' '*'                                                                                                       130  [] 17:46 ksaito:~
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
/dev/cu.usbserial-*****F*F*B
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
/dev/tty.usbserial-*****F*F*B
```

開発環境は、MacOSで、VSCode+PlatformIOを使って簡単なプログラムをビルドしました。

platformio.iniの２パターンでアップロードしたところ、いずれも失敗しました。
MacOS13でプログラムのアップロードが成功している事例があれば、情報いただけないでしょうか。

### パターン１

upload_portに`/dev/cu`を指定する。

```
[env:m5stack-core2]
platform = espressif32
board = m5stack-core2
framework = arduino
lib_deps = m5stack/M5Stack@^0.4.4
upload_port = /dev/cu.usbserial-*****F*F*B
```

アップロード結果は、下記の通りで、M5StackCPlusがフリーズしました。

```
esptool.py v4.5.1
Serial port /dev/cu.usbserial-*****F*F*B

A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/cu.usbserial-*****F*F*B, the port doesn't exist
*** [upload] Error 2
======================================= [FAILED] Took 2.08 seconds =======================================
```

### パターン２

upload_portに`/dev/tty`を指定する。

```
[env:m5stack-core2]
platform = espressif32
board = m5stack-core2
framework = arduino
lib_deps = m5stack/M5Stack@^0.4.4
upload_port = /dev/cu.usbserial-*****F*F*B
```

アップロード結果は、下記の通り

```
Serial port /dev/tty.usbserial-*****F*F*B
Connecting.....
Chip is ESP32-PICO-D4 (revision v1.0)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, Embedded Flash, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 460800
Changed.

A fatal error occurred: Unable to verify flash chip connection (No serial data received.).
*** [upload] Error 2
====================================== [FAILED] Took 12.79 seconds ======================================
```

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。

準備したデバイスと違うものを設定してプロジェクトを作成していたことが原因でした。

今回、準備したデバイスは、M5StackC-plus1.1でした。
最初の設定と動作するようになった設定は、下記の通りです。

| 設定 | 最初の設定 | 動作するようになった設定 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| New Project - Board | `M5Stack Core2` | `M5Stack-C (M5Stack)` |
| New Project - Framework | Arduino | Arduino |
| platform.ini - lib_deps | `m5stack/M5Stack@^0.4.4` | `m5stack/M5StickCPlus@^0.0.9` |

`upload_port`の設定は、不要でPlatformIOのAdd M5Stackで`/dev/tty.*`を選択でアップロードされました。

VCPドライバーがMacOS13で動作していないのかと考えましたが、1.5.0のドライバーで問題なく動作しました。
lib_depsは、PlatformIOの設定画面でたくさん表示され、上の方に表示されているM5Stackが共通のライブラリと勘違いしてしまいました。
準備したデバイスごとに、ライブラリが準備されているようです。